# ITEM expected input to be a string or list but got the number 0 instead error. How would I fix this?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make a model in netlogo that can simulate various versions of langton's ant. I have the basic code already (which is not polished up yet, apologies for that). from a chooser in the interface, the user chooses a path that the ant (the turtle) takes, and turns either left or right depending on the color of the patch he is on. to turn the strings in the chooser into a usable code, I am using the following code (only partially included the walk execution, if you want the entire thig

```
to make-state-sequence
  if mychoice = "[own input]"
  [
    ifelse 2 <= length own-LR-string and length own-LR-string <= 12 and remove "L" remove "R" own-LR-string = ""[
      set state-sequence own-LR-string][print "Invalid, can only contain L and R, and must be 2-12 symbols" stop]
  ] set N length state-sequence

  if mychoice = "[Random sequence]"
    [
     let random-length 2 + random 10
     let random-sequence n-values random-length [one-of ["L" "R"]]
      set state-sequence random-sequence
    ]
  set N length state-sequence
  if table:has-key? instruction-table mychoice [
    set state-sequence table:get instruction-table mychoice]
  set N length state-sequence
end
 
to walk
  ask turtles [
    if bumped? = true [stop]
    let direction item [state] of patch-here state-sequence
    if direction = "L" [
      left 90
    ]
    if direction = "R" [
      right 90
    ]
```

here, the `state-sequence` is important; it is the string that is chosen in the chooser used in the interface.
doing this will make the setup button work fine, but using the walk button gives the following error:

> ITEM expected input to be a string or list but got the number 0 instead.

I have tried turning the `let direction item [state] of patch-here state-sequence` portion into an ifelse statement; because if the symbol is not an L, it would automatically be an R. it didn't change the error.
I suspect the `state-sequence` is not recognised as a string. is there a possible fix for this? I also tried using a to-report in combination with reduce, but we got stuck on that as well.

for good measure, here are some snippets of the widgets in the interface:

[the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpkRj.png)

[the chooser editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBsif.png)

[the info tab, if you would like to see it. has some deeper explanation on how langton's ant works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv4x6.png)

Comment: is the variable 'bumped?' a turtle variable, global variable, interface widget? My guess is that it is not initialised anywhere to true/false - the error message is telling you that the value is 0, which is NetLogo's default. And it doesn't know how to test 0 for truth status.

Answer (score 2):

As JenB commented above,  it seems likely that "state-sequence" for "patch-here" was never initialized or set, so it has defaulted to the number 0.

You could check whether state-sequence was a list or string as the first real step in your ask turtles [ ] section and to throw an informative error if it is not.

Incidentally, your sequence of if-statements in make-state-sequence is a risky coding structure as zero or more than one of the conditions could fire.   Possibly in your case zero of them were matched.

```
;;  This structure may fire multiple conditions
;;   with later actions possibly overriding earlier actions
;;   and has the possibility that none of the conditions are met
;;   If TWO conditions are matched, BOTH fire in that order and the SECOND one 
;;    may overwrite the FIRST one.

        ( condition1 )    [ action1 ]
        ( condition2 )    [ action2 ]
                ;; ...
        ( conditionn )    [ actionn ]

;; The following structure exits after the first succeessful condition is met.
;; and guarantees that there is always exactly one case matched
;;   which might be the default case .
;;  if a second condition might have been matched is unknown because the 
;;    code never gets that far.
;;
;;   This is slightly obscurely hidden in the dictionary under "ifelse"
;;    and further confused if you believe "choice" is a reserved word or the
;;    only way you can test a condition.  I tested the following and it works.

  (
     ifelse
        ( condition1 )    [ action1 ]
        ( condition2 )    [ action2 ]
                ;; ...
        ( conditionn )    [ actionn ]
                ;; else
                          [ default action ]
  )
```

Here's sample code that demonstrates testing what value you have and showing that the zero value resulting from not having set the patches sequence could be detected by the
?is-string and ?is-list tests.  It also demonstrates using the CHOICE structure.

```
patches-own [ x ]

to  setup
  clear-all 
  
  let z n-values 8 [one-of ["L" "R"]]
  if is-list? z[ print "it's a list" ]
  if is-string? z [ print "it's a string" ]
  
  
     let a 46
     let b 43
     let c "dog"
     let d "cat"
  

  (
     ifelse
        ( a = 4 )               [ print "a is 4 " ]
        ( b = 4 )               [ print "b is 4 " ]
    ( c = "dog" and d = "cat")  [ print "strange choice "]
          ; else
                  [ print "I fell through to the else condition" ]
  )
  
  
  create-turtles 1
    
  ask turtles [
    print ( word "\n x = "  x ) 
    print ( word "is x a number? " is-number? x )
    print ( word "is x a list? "   is-list?   x )
    print ( word "is x a string? " is-string? x )
    ]
  
  ask patch 0 0 [ set x n-values 8 [one-of ["L" "R"]]]
    
    
  ask turtles [
    print ( word "\n x = "  x ) 
    print ( word "is x a number? " is-number? x )
    print ( word "is x a list? "   is-list?   x )
    print ( word "is x a string? " is-string? x )
    ]

    
reset-ticks
end
```